# VBA copy from 2 excel files with 2 conditions

Tags: vba, excel

i want to copy the names on Column A in source.xlsm to destination.xlsm ONLY if the name doesn't exist , if it doesn't existe it should be written at the end of destination.xlsm column .

i didn't know how to continue the code

```
Sub Recopy()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
dim Lastlign as integer 
'## Open both workbooks
Set x = Workbooks.Open("P:\Desktop\Source.xlsm")
Set y = Workbooks.Open(" P:\Desktop\Destination.xlsm")

'Now, copy 
x.Sheets("name of copying sheet").Range("A1").Copy

'Now, paste to y worksheet:

y.Sheets("sheetname").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

x.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: you want to look at the Range.Find Method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx You basically go row by row in Column A in Source.xlsm (e.g. with a for loop), and check whether you can find this name in destination.xlsm. If not, you write it, else you go to the next row and check again...

Comment: Also, for writing the name into destination, it would be better to use something like `y.Sheets("bla").Range("bla").Value = x.Sheets("aaa").Range("aaa").Value` instead of copy pasting.

Comment: If you really only want the names (nothing in the other columns) the easiest way (code-wise) could be to just copy everything and then [remove the duplicates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823.aspx). This assumes that there are no duplicate names in the columns already that you want to keep.

Comment: but how can i loop throught those cells in source.xlxs and affected to a value in destination.xlsx ?

Comment: if activesheet.cells(i,1).value = ?? the cells in the source xlsx .. how can i continue ?

Comment: you should ask every question you have by posting a separate question in SO. While typing, SO will guide you to similar questions already answered. If you can't get the result you need, post the detailed question with the code you have tried and we will be happy to assist.

Comment: @JeanLo: with a `for-loop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added comments to explain what's happening in this code - if you're not sure about any of it just comment...

```
Sub Recopy()
Dim sourceWb As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim destWb As Workbook
Dim destLast As Integer
Dim destSheet As Worksheet
dim Lastlign as integer 
dim myLoop as Integer
'## Open both workbooks
Set sourceWb = Workbooks.Open("P:\Desktop\Source.xlsm")
Set sourceSheet = sourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet name in here")
Set destWb = Workbooks.Open(" P:\Desktop\Destination.xlsm")
Set destSheet = destWb.Worksheets("Sheet name in here")

' get the last line of the source sheet so we know how many rows to loop over
Lastlign = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For myLoop = 1 to Lastlign ' start from 2 if you have a header in row 1
    sourceVal = sourceSheet.Range("A" & myLoop).Value
    With destSheet.Range("A:A")
        Set oFound = .Find(sourceVal)
        If oFound Is Nothing Then
           ' didn't locate the value in col A of destSheet
           ' find last populated row in destination sheet and add 1 for first empty row
           destLast = destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
           ' set value in destination sheet
           destSheet.Range("A" & destLast).Value = sourceVal 
        End If
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your help , but  when i execute the code nothing happens . Error message like: the destWb is already opened  and i ll loose all the modifications , because here when i put the code vba . how can i edit it ?  @Dave

Comment: Since the script includes commands to open both workbooks, it will fail if either of them is already open.  Just comment out the 2 `Workbooks.Open` lines if you have both files open already.

Comment: but then the destWb will not be defined

Comment: `Set destWb = Workbooks("Destination.xlsm")` will set the reference for an already open workbook.  You'll need to do the same for `Source.xlsm`